# How to get all notifications on click of app icon?

Tags: objective-c

My setup is as per the documentation from Apple and I can receive push notifications.

The following are the expected behaviours when a PN comes in:

**App is in the background and I click on the notification:** I can see the notification in notification center. Click on the notification, the app comes to the foreground and I can see the above method is called.
**App is active and already in the foreground:** I can see the above method is called.
Now, the following is the peculiar behaviour I am seeing:

PN comes in. See it in the notifications, see the badge on the app icon. I click on the app icon - not the notification: In this instance I found that the above method is not called. I was expecting it to be called...
Has anyone seen this behaviour before? Is this what should happen? I couldn't see anything in the Apple documentation regarding this... Also, would there be a way around this?